# How do I detect if a UTF-8 file uses code-points versus binary encoding?

Tags: unicode, binary, nltk

I have a text file in UTF-8 encoding, but how do I detect if it is in code-points versus binary? I ask because NLTK (https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) says I have to decode it from binary, if it is in that form. Note the overloading of the word "encoding."

Asking because a software package using punkt is choking on a file and I want to verify it's not in binary format. Thanks!

I have tried detecting encoding in Emacs, but it only returns UTF-8, which really isn't my question. Recognizing coding system software doesn't provide the answer either.

Comment: "*NLTK ... says I have to decode it from binary*" - where does it say that? In any case, UTF-8 has an easily recognizable bit pattern, so it would not be difficult to scan the first few bytes of the file to see whether they are encoded in UTF-8 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are character encodings, not code points. Code points refer to the numerical values assigned to each character in a character set, such as the Unicode character set. When you have a text file in UTF-8 encoding, it means that the characters in the file are represented using the UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: Yes, but it was my misunderstanding of encode/decode that was causing the problem. Here is a nifty utility that illustrates the problem. NLTK only accepts the "decoded" version of Unicode for parsing. https://checkserp.com/encode/utf8/ Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that it needs a Python string rather than bytes. Text mode is the default for the `open` function. The phrasing in the documentation is awkward, and harks back to the complexities of using Unicode in environments where both Python2 and Python3 needed to be considered.

If you are reading from a file:

1. Ensure you open text mode rather than binary mode, and
2. Its safer to specify the encoding. Most systems use UTF-8 as the default, but Windows can be quirky.

So in Python: `open(file, mode='r', encoding="utf-8")`. You could be more explicit and use `open(file, mode='rt', encoding="utf-8")` to indicate reading in text mode, but text mode is the default, so it isn't necessary.

It is contrasted with `open(file, mode='rb', encoding="utf-8")` which would open the file in binary mode.

If the text file was generated on windows, it may have a Byte Order Mark (BOM) so opening the file with `encoding="utf-8-sig"` would be needed.

SO basically all its sawing is open the file in Python 3 with default read mode and ensure that the file is read using the right encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is tricky, and not always consistent between languages and domains.

A UTF-8 file can be seen as text file or as binary file:

- text file in C / Unix interpretation (so in many languages which were inspired with C API): `\0` is used only to terminate strings, the new lines (NL, CR, LF) are interpreted as usual in C, and there is a sequence of bytes, named *char*acters, but also on initial times we could use for multibytes strings (e.g. shift encoding, etc.). In this case UTF-8 can be seen as text. Just note that there are multibytes characters, but also with "codepoints" we have multi-codepoints glyphs (which should not be split in two). So most operating systems and utilities will read UTF-8 as *text*, and they may be able to decode it without user interventions.
- binary: Python uses the *binary* then the bytes have a fix values, so all encoded text is binary. Text is about abstraction, like *Unicode string* in Unicode standard: it is about a sequence of codepoints: we know the values of codepoints, but we (mostly) ignore how such strings/sequence of codepoints is stored (in fact Python3 started with an internal representation, and later it changed with a more dynamic ones: 1 byte for Latin1, 2 bytes for UCS-2, 4 bytes for the rest, plus some extra data (length, format, size of buffer, etc.). Note: it works well with Python because strings are immutable. Python view is handy to program: binary = encoded, text = decoded (and so where you need to know the encoding and where not). But then it changed the meaning of "binary".

But there is only one UTF-8 (or maybe you can distinguish a dialect with or without the BOM/signature, which are the first 3 bytes).

Note: we may get a similar error with *characters*. For C and Unix a char is a bytes (8-bit) (C technically allowed larger characters, but good luck on exchanging data!). Some may see a character as wchar_t (wide char) e.g. when dealing with UTF-16 or UTF-32. Unicode (and Python) consider character a codepoint. (also here: technically a character is a codepoint, but some codepoints are not characters: for few special/reserved/surrogates characters, but Unicode also wrote they may uses both terms interchangeably.

So: do not be too strict on terminology: use a grain of salt to interpret it within the context.